# To Get the VM Created Date

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere

I am new to the VMWare Sdk Programming,i have a requirement to get the Virtual Machine (VM) Deployed date.

I have written the below code to get the other required details.

```
package com.vmware.vim25.mo.samples;

import java.net.URL;

import com.vmware.vim25.*;
import com.vmware.vim25.mo.*; 


public class HelloVM {


     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
     {
     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     int i;
     ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL("https://bgl-clvs-vc.bgl.com/sdk"), "sbibi", "sibi_123", true);
     long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("time taken:" + (end-start));
     Folder rootFolder = si.getRootFolder();
     String name = rootFolder.getName();
     System.out.println("root:" + name);
     ManagedEntity[] mes = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntities("VirtualMachine");


     System.out.println("No oF vm:" + mes.length);
     if(mes==null || mes.length ==0)
     {
         return;
     }
     for(i=0;i<mes.length; i++){

         VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) mes[i];

         VirtualMachineConfigInfo vminfo = vm.getConfig();
         VirtualMachineCapability vmc = vm.getCapability();
         vm.getResourcePool();
         System.out.println("VM Name " + vm.getName());
         System.out.println("GuestOS: " + vminfo.getGuestFullName());
         System.out.println("Multiple snapshot supported: " + vmc.isMultipleSnapshotsSupported());
         System.out.println("Summary: " + vminfo.getDatastoreUrl()); 
     }


     si.getServerConnection().logout();

     } 


}
```

Can anyone help me how I can get the VM created date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Vm Creation Date using the below codes.

```
EventFilterSpecByUsername uFilter =
new EventFilterSpecByUsername();
uFilter.setSystemUser(false);
uFilter.setUserList(new String[] {"administrator"});
Event[] events = evtMgr.queryEvents(efs);
// print each of the events
for(int i=0; events!=null && i<events.length; i++)  
{
      System.out.println("\nEvent #" + i); 
      printEvent(events[i]);
}

/**
* Only print an event as Event type.
*/
 static void printEvent(Event evt)
 {
    String typeName = evt.getClass().getName();
    int lastDot = typeName.lastIndexOf('.');
     if(lastDot != -1)
      {
           typeName = typeName.substring(lastDot+1);
       }
           System.out.println("Time:" + evt.getCreatedTime().getTime());
   }
```

Hope this code might help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
private DateTime GetVMCreatedDate(VirtualMachine vm)
    {
        var date = DateTime. Now;
        var userName = new EventFilterSpecByUsername ();
        userName . SystemUser = false;
        var filter = new EventFilterSpec ();
        filter . UserName = userName;
        filter . EventTypeId = ( new String [] { "VmCreatedEvent" , "VmBeingDeployedEvent" ,"VmRegisteredEvent" , "VmClonedEvent" });
        var collector = vm .GetEntityOnlyEventsCollectorView(filter);
        foreach (Event e in collector . ReadNextEvents(1 ))
        {
            Console .WriteLine(e . GetType(). ToString() + " :" + e. CreatedTime);
            date = e. CreatedTime;
        }

        Console .WriteLine( "---------------------------------------------------" );
        return date;
    }
```