# How to get vm creation time from the machine's properties

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I'm using vijava (5.1) to fetch data from a vCenter about virtual machines.
For that matter I'm using a filter with some properties (for example, guest.hostName, runtime.powerState etc.).
I need to get the creation time for these virtual machines and from what I saw, [this info is available in the event logs of the vCenter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666839/to-get-the-vm-created-date)

Is there a way to get this info part of the virtual machine's properties?
I searched this info using the vSphere-Client and I didn't - so I guess the only place is from the event logs - but just to be sure, is that the only way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to get creation time of virtual machine using vijava api. However you can get other below informations from VirtualMachineConfigInfo.

1. changeVersion : The changeVersion is a unique identifier for a given version of the configuration. Each change to the configuration updates this value. This is typically implemented as an ever increasing count or a time-stamp. However, a client should always treat this as an opaque string.
2. modified : Last time a virtual machine's configuration was modified.

   `Folder rootFolder = serviceInstance.getRootFolder();
   InventoryNavigator inventoryNavigator = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder);
   vm = (VirtualMachine) inventoryNavigator.searchManagedEntity(VirtualMachine.class.getSimpleName(), vmName);
   VirtualMachineConfigInfo vmConfig = vm.getConfig();
   System.out.println(vmConfig.getChangeVersion);`

[image for information in virtualMachineConfigInfo object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptN68.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set the creation time as an extra config property then the event log is the only way I know of. If you want to go the extra config route I created a [sample](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/add_vm_extra_config_tags.py) that shows how to use them that is part of the pyvmomi-community-samples project.